# How to pass parameter from body page to header page in tiles?

Tags: jsp, tiles

My tiles layout page has three section i.e. header, body and footer.

The layout is such that the title of page has to be defined in the header. Is there any way I can title from body page to the header page?

tiles.xml

```
<definition name="mobile.base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/mobile/layout/baseLayout.jsp">
   <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/mobile/common/header.jsp" />
   <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/mobile/common/menu.jsp" />
   <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/mobile/common/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

layout.jsp

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <header id="header">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"  />
            </header>

            <div id="mainPage">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer id="footer">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"  />
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

header.jsp

```
    <header id="header">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <aside class="span1">
        <div class="btn-group menu-highlight">
            <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span>+</span>
            </button> 
           <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <h1><img src="img/logo-text.jpg" width="106" height="23" alt=" " /> <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></h1>
            <ul class="">
            <li><a href="#" class="active"><span>Home</span> <b><img src="img/icon-home.png" width="19" height="17" alt=" " /></b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Account</span> <b><i class="icon-star"></i></b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span> <b><i class="icon-comment"></i></b></a></li>                                
                <li><a href="#"><span>Calender</span> <b><i class="icon-calendar"></i></b></a></li>                                                
            </ul>
           </div>

        </div>
    </aside>
    <section class="span11 head-right-panel">
        <header>
         <hgroup class="span8"><h1 class="ellipsis"> Page Title</h1></hgroup>
        <span class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.jpg" width="118" height="41" alt=" " />  
        </span>    
        </header>
    </section>
  </div>  
</div>
</header>
```

If you see the header.jsp there is page title. Ideally we will want a placeholder over there which should get replaced by the page title defined in the each body.jsp

Comment: No. However you can create another definition from mobile.base.definition, this definition will set the body template and in doing so may over ride other parameters in the mobile.base.definition which are required for this particular body (perhaps css and js files), just a guess but if this is the case using list attributes in the base you can add additional list items in the derived definition (appending new CSS files and JS files as needed). For an example of this see: http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/advanced/list-attributes.html

Comment: Perhaps I was too hasty, it may be possible if you apply custom programming to the solution in the form of a view preparer. The preparer would look at the current definition and then modify the definition depending on the state of the body. I think you should probably avoid this because when you look at a tiles definition everything makes sense as soon as you see a view preparer on a definition who knows what is happening unless you look at the code.